# git revert changes except go extension files

Tags: linux, git

git revert HEAD reverts all changes, but what I want to revert the ones except my go extension files? I want to revert all changes except the one with *.go

I tried

```
   git revert HEAD ^*.go
   git revert HEAD *.go?
```

None of them works. Where should I look up to find this feature?

Comment: Should this be done recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `revert` function is used to revert an entire commit

From `git revert --help`

> Given one or more existing commits, revert the changes that the related patches
>          introduce, and record some new commits that record them. This requires your
>          working tree to be clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit).

So you cannot do a partial revert.

You have to edit the comment that you want to revert and split it in two different commit: one with all your `*.go` files, and the other one with all the other files. Then, you can revert the correct commit.